# Алгоритм поиска в тексте

Tags: java, алгоритм

Всем доброго времени суток. Хотел бы выслушать идеи алгоритмов для следующего задания. Пишу на Java. Имеется .txt фаил допустим:

```
    стул,стол,книга,табуретка
    диван,мусор,ноутбук,стол
    ручка,зарядка,мышь,лампа
```

Я запрашиваю у пользователя слово. Допустим слово - стол. И мне нужно вывести в другой .txt фаил только те столбцы где находится слово стол, т.е в данном примере было бы:

```
    стол
    мусор
    зарядка
    табуретка
    стол
    лампа
```

P.s была идея идти по строке, проверять каждое слово на сходство, и при этом вести счётчик для каждой итерации по словам в строке. Т.е если бы во второй строке попалось бы нужное слово, то индекс добавлял бы в массив. На выходе у меня был бы массив с номерами столбцов в которых есть искомое слово. Но как следовать дальше не знаю. Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше идти не по строкам, а по столбцам. Тогда если в столбце встретилось слово, то можно сразу вывести этот столбец и перейти к следующему.

```
String wordToFind = ...
String[][] words = ...

int numberRows = words.length;
int numberColumns = words[0].length;

for (int j = 0; j < numberColumns; ++j) {
    boolean columnContainsWord = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberRows; ++i) {
        if (wordToFind.equals(words[i][j])) {
            columnContainsWord = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (columnContainsWord) {
        // выводим столбец
        for (int i = 0; i < numberRows; ++i) {
            System.out.println(words[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ещё попутный вопрос, как проще всего загнать это из фаила в двумерный массив?

Comment: Если вы знаете число строк в файле, то создаёте двумерный массив: `String[][] matrix = new String[число_строк][]`, считываете файл построчно, строку разбиваете на массив слов с помощью метода [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). На `i`-ой итерации будет что-то вроде `matrix[i] = line.split(',')`. Если не знаете число строк, то создаёте `ArrayList<String[]>`, на каждой итерации добавляете в него массив слов, полученный из строчки таким же образом.